# How can I address this error: InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))?

Tags: python, pandas, url, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I get this error:
InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))

when I try to run this code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
url_file = 'https://github.com/MarissaFosse/ryersoncapstone/raw/master/DailyNewsArticles.xlsx'

tstar_articles = pd.read_excel(url_file, "TorontoStar Articles", header=0) 

url_to_sents = {}

for url in tstar_articles:
  url = tstar_articles['URL']
  page = requests.get(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  results = soup.find(class_='c-article-body__content') 
  results_text = [tag.get_text().strip() for tag in results]
  sentence_list = [sentence for sentence in results_text if not '\n' in sentence]
  sentence_list = [sentence for sentence in sentence_list if '.' in sentence]
  article = ' '.join(sentence_list)
  url_to_sents[url] = article
```

I'm trying to use requests() to read a URL from an Excel file I've created. I suspect it's due to unseen characters, but don't know how to check for any.

Comment: Instead of pasting the line of code from the stack trace that *creates* the exception, give us the text of the exception itself. (Including the whole stack trace is also generally good practice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you iterate over the returned dataframe, it returns only the column names. Thus, your original code first assigned `Date` to `url`, then `Category`, and so on; these strings do not have URLs, thus the error.

By contrast, looking up any column in the dataframe returns a series you can iterate over. Thus, instead of iterating over `tstar_articles` when you want the URLs, iterate over `tstar_articles['URL']`:

Thus, instead of:

```
for url in tstar_articles:
    url = tstar_articles['URL']
    page = requests.get(url)
```

...use:

```
for url in tstar_articles['URL']:
    page = requests.get(url)
```

Comment: Modified to contain explanation rather than bare code. @MarissaFosse, consider clicking the checkbox next to the answer to mark your problem solved.